My JWT token is said to be expired 2 months ago when I just created the token, what causes this problem?
I'm making a web application that has a function for users to add different artists to their favorite-list. The login function works and users get a JWT upon logging in, I even added logging to the console to check the time of when the token is created. (see image below) 
This is the code of my auth.service.ts:
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';
import { CreateUserDto } from '../users/dto/CreateUser.dto';
import { LoginUserDto } from './dto/LoginUser.dto';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService
  ) {}

  async register(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<any> {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(createUserDto.password, 10);
    return this.usersService.createUser({ ...createUserDto, password: hashedPassword });
  }

  async login(loginUserDto: LoginUserDto): Promise<{ access_token: string }> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findByEmail(loginUserDto.email);
    if (user && await bcrypt.compare(loginUserDto.password, user.password)) {
      const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user._id, role: user.role };
      console.log('Payload:', payload);
      const currentTime = new Date();
      console.log('Current Server Time (during token generation):', currentTime.toISOString());
      const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload, { expiresIn: '60m' });
      console.log('Generated Token:', token);

      const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
      console.log('Decoded Token:', decodedToken);

      return {
        access_token: token,
      };
    }
    throw new UnauthorizedException();
  }
}

However, the problem arises when I try to add an artist to their favorite-list in Postman , as you can see the expiredAt date is changed to a date more than 2 months prior to creating the JWT. (see images below) 
What causes this problem, since all the system's times seem to be right.

could you try const decodedToken = this.jwtService.decode(token);

@NarenMurali That didn't fix the problem unfortunately.

we can see you are creating a token client-side.  We can't see if you store it or if it's only in state. How are you using that in postman?  (A client-side generated token should not allow any server-authorization anyway... the claims must be signed by server's private key and validated server-side using same)  It's fine to use to show/hide certain client-side GUI stuff, but otherwise you need server to create authorization/access token.  (but doing that user lookup kind of defeats the purpose of the access token, and you're serving the hashed password via endpoint)
